# Eigenvalues of $A$ and $|A|$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose that $A$ is a real $n\times n$ matrix. Suppose further that $|A|$ (absolute values taken entry-wise) has only real eigenvalues on the unit circle and that the spectral radius $\rho(|A|)$ satisfies $\rho(|A|)\le 1$.

Then also $\rho(A)\le 1$. But does it also follow that $A$ has no complex eigenvalues on the unit circle or could $A$ have a complex eigenvalue on the unit circle but $|A|$ has only real eigenvalues there?

Comment: Are all of the eigenvalues assumed to be *on* the circle?

Comment: Consider $A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\ -1&0 \end{bmatrix}$. Better yet, consider $A=[i]$.

Comment: The second example above is wrong because $A$ is real.